# How to interpret my profile likelihood plots (three-level meta-analysis)?

Tags: variance, interpretation, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, profile-likelihood

I conducted a three-level meta-analysis to test effects of non-driving related tasks on take-over quality in highly automated driving. When it now comes to interpretation of the results, I struggle to find the right answers. I already know that my research is contaminated by publication bias, but still I am trying to correctly interpret some results.

One of them are these profile likelihood plots, that indicate the likelihood of the estimated variance. The second plot does not show a curve, but rather a line. Can someone give me a hint of what I can interpret out of this line? Am I right, that the likelihood of not having variance at this level is high?

[image: Profile likelihood plots]

Comment: Presumably it reflects the estimated value of $\sigma_2^2$ being zero?

Answer (score 4):

The peak is at $\sigma^2_2 = 0$ and hence this is the ML/REML estimate of this variance component. Since profiling for variance components is done for non-negative value of the variance, you don't get a peak like for $\sigma^2_1$, but a line/curve that goes down. That is perfectly fine. And yes, it indicates that the most likely value for $\sigma^2_2$ given the data is 0. However, you might also want to examine the profile likelihood confidence interval for the variance components (which you can get with `confint()`). It will probably be quite wide for $\sigma^2_2$ and hence, while the most likely value if 0, other values greater than 0 cannot be rejected either.

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang, your answer helped a lot for my further analysis! Best Regards